# Is stoppage time representative of the true time that was lost?

Tags: football

As far as I know, stoppage time is at the discretion of the referee. When the half time is full, they decide the time that is to be added by themselves, at their discretion, and then after that amount of minutes is passed, the referee can call the half finished at any time (but they usually wait for a moment where there is not a probable scoring play ongoing).

But I wonder, was there any statistical study, ever, if that stoppage time is usually about right on how long the ball was really in a 'dead-ball' state? Or does usually the referees under/over estimate the amount of time the ball was dead?

(By a dead ball state I mean moments where there is no play, like when the players reset after a goal, or substitutions, injuries, etc.)

I would guess such a study has been done at some point, I just have no clue where to look.

Comment: Stoppage time is explicitly not intended to account for all time that the ball is out of play or in "a dead ball state". Resetting after a goal is a natural part of play and should very rarely be counted in stoppage time, and only to the extent the teams take longer than necessary, for example.

Comment: I always tought the Stoppage time was to try and recoup all the time where the ball was not in play so players do play a full 45 minutes half (but without being annoying with counting every dead ball second on the board). Am I wrong on that assumtion?

Comment: Yes, that is a wrong assumption. The ball going out of play, setting up for a free kick, celebrating a goal, are all natural parts of the game, and so is the time used up  Only if the stoppage becomes longer than normal or unusual, should time be added.

Comment: And the 'longer than usual' is at the discretion of the referee, so due to the fact that its definition is VERY loose there can't be a count afterwards to show if it was more or less than what really happened.

Comment: Indeed, even if the referee applies a perfectly consistent standards, what is "normal" for *this* game can be much quicker than *that* game.